# How to get values from Redis using keys which contains spaces?

Tags: redis, key

Using telnet I type in command line commands like this

```
get field with spaces
get "field with spaces"
get 'field with spaces'
```

And all this three return same error.

```
-ERR wrong number of arguments for 'get' command
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only have telnet (and not 'redis-cli'), then you need to use the Redis binary-safe unified protocol to use spaces in key names, for example:

```
telnet localhost 6379
*2
$3
GET
$17
field with spaces
hello (this is Redis answer if "field with spaces" contains value "hello")

Explanation:
*2 = Number of arguments (first arg is "GET" and second is "field with spaces")
$3 = length of first argument ("GET" contains 3 bytes)
$17 = length of second argument ("field with spaces" contains 17 bytes)
```

More information about Redis binary-safe protocol: http://redis.io/topics/protocol

Answer (score 15):

What version of redis are you using? It works fine for me on 2.2.2 using double quotes

```
root@this:~# redis-cli
redis> set "test space" hello
OK
redis> get "test space"
"hello"
redis> get 'test space'
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'get' command
redis>
```

Comment: I don't have a ssh access. I use telnet connection.

Comment: @user769353 You can connect with redis-cli also to other hosts' Redis servers, use -h parameter (`redis-cli -h 8.8.8.8`)!

Answer (score 5):

get "field\ with\ spaces"

that worked for me.