# Mosquitto ACL, Redis backend not working with topic having space

Tags: redis, mqtt, acl, mosquitto

I am working on Mosquitto, and using Redis as the back end to handle both username/password pair authentication and ACL. I am using [JPmens](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug)' authentication plugin to do this.

mosquitto conf:

```
auth_opt_backends redis
auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so
auth_opt_redis_host 127.0.0.1
auth_opt_redis_port 6379
auth_opt_redis_userquery GET %s
auth_opt_redis_aclquery GET %s-%s
```

Everything is working fine. But when I start using topic with spaces, it simply denied me from publish/subscribe.

I have already set this topic value in Redis:

```
SET "user1-sample topic" 2
```

Mosquitto logs:

```
Denied PUBLISH from sample_publisher (d0, q2, r0, m1, 'sample topic', ... (10 bytes))
```

Is there anything, I can do to make this work, like acl query change or change in redis-data.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6122851/504554) question and answers it implies that the following query may work:

```
auth_opt_redis_aclquery GET "%s-%s%"
```

Comment: In that case then it's likely to require a code change in the plugin, you should raise an issue against the github project

Comment: Ok, I will raise this. Thanks for your suggestion.